# Failed to resolve test runner dependency in gradle

Tags: android

I am creating new project in android studio but after building project it is showing error below:

```
ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.1
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app

ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx.test:runner:1.2.1
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app
```

Below is my gradle files dependencies:

**app.gradle**

```
dependencies {

def lifecycle_version = "2.0.0"
def room_version = "2.2.0-alpha01"

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.1'

//View model and live data
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"

//Room
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version"

}
```

**Notes**

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

  }
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
  }
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
   }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Someone please let me know why above error is showing and how can I overcome it. Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Answer (score 0):

Where did your version come from? Official only to 3.1.0

Reference this https://developer.android.com/training/testing/set-up-project

Comment: Ohh, my mistake actually it was 3.2.0 and I was upgrading it to wrong version 3.2.1.